# i want to ban certain prefix

Tags: php

if i've input text where visitor should enter own URL

```
<form name="frm" method="post" action="addlink.php">
url : <input type="text" name="url" id="url">
<button type="submit" class="options green">add</button>
</form>
```

and addlink.php code like this

```
$url = $_POST['url']; 
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table_urls (url) VALUES ('$url')";
mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
```

i want to ban for example www.something.com/anything so if the visitor enter any url has www.something.com/else - www.something.com/elsething ..etc

it detect something.com and gives error like

```
<?PHP if(XXXXXXXX){
echo "somthing.com is not allowed";
}else{
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table_urls (url) VALUES ('$url')";
mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

if what ! i wanna say if `$url` has any something.com then give not allowed !

Comment: **WARNING** Your code is massively open to SQL Injection attacks. If you insist on using `mysql_query`, you at least need to utilize [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to escape your values before using them in queries. You'd be even better served to upgrade yourself to [`PDO`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) and the use of prepared statements instead of the `mysql*` extensions.

Comment: @rdlowrey thanks but this is example for simplicity but in real example sure i'll use mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: After using the older `mysql` functions for the past decade... I second the @rdlowrey `PDO` suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP's function, `preg_match()` to find the exact match:

```
if (preg_match('/something.com/i', $url) > 0) {
    // Your error message here
}
```

For more information on using that function, you can check here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1):

I wanted the same thing. I did it in VB but check here if this helps
[Extract words from a string and verify whether or not they exist in a database in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201592/extract-words-from-a-string-and-verify-whether-or-not-they-exist-in-a-database-i)

Just split words at spaces and verify if the value exists in your database. If it does, then replace with `****` or anything you want and while filtering words use a StringBuilder which will append each word only if the word contains banned value it will append `****` and your original string will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
$parsed_url=parse_url($url);    
if (strtolower($parsed_url['host']) == 'www.something.com' || strtolower($parsed_url['host']) == 'something.com')
{
   $error=true;
}
```

Comment: thanks but what about if it was www.something.com/anything/something , i need any url that started with something.com is to be not allowed.

Comment: I edited my answer and would appreciate if those downvotes would be taken back. Thanks. :-)